# iOS Keyboard Backspace and Foreward-space Capabilities

Tags: keyboard, ios-appstore, jailbreak, macos

Is there an app (or a way in settings, that despite searching I cannot seem to figure out) that can change the keypad on an iOS device to allow for both forward and backward delete (or delete/backspace depending on your outlook on semantics), like the OS X offers? This is the one big drawback for me with Apple vs. other mobile devices. Editing is much more difficult without this feature.

If not, is there a away to do this if I jailbreak my device(s)?

Comment: There are lots of 3rd party keyboards for iOS.  Have you researched a bunch of them and not found any that do this?

Comment: I haven't spent a day on it, but i've looked at quite a few options as far as settings or app store. I do not have a jailbroken device so have not looked at that option (which is why I asked here).

Comment: I also checked on here and didn't find anything addressing the issue. Lots of complaints online about the issue of the iOS not having it generally, but I don't trust that it doesn't exist somewhere/somehow based on that, as many didn't realize its possible on a Macbook.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no way to do this without a jailbreak. The software keyboard has no functionality to do what you want, and as a developer, I know that there is not way to program any other delete but the backspace.

As for the jailbreak, I am sure there is a way, but make sure you Google it first, since I wouldn't jailbreak without knowing for a fact.

Comment: Got it! I just deleted my comment, lol

Comment: Sorry about that. I mean w/out.

Comment: No problem. We all skim over things now and then

Comment: I wondered if there was a Jailbreak version only b/c if there was, I would think an app would be coming in iOS offering same, since they tend to get a few ideas now and then from those sites :~). I'd probably be hesitant to do that anyway...but who knows.

Comment: Well, maybe Apple will add in in the future, but as of today, I think your best bet is with a jailbreak

Comment: Ok, thank you. There are a bunch of wacky keyboards, even mini ones, its surprising this is still an issue. It really is a helpful feature and when I switched from android to iPhone I had a real problem adjusting.